# jQuery Clone Recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

Why is this "copy"(click) wrong, it binds all the previous handlers as well:

```
var add = function(element) {
  var ele = element.clone(true);
  $('.container').append(ele);
  $('.copy', new).click(function(){ add(ele); });
}
```

Idea: I want to have an element text next to a "copy" button.
When I click "copy", it clones the current row and append it to the container.
But this seems to be recursive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `true` parameter says:](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

> Normally, any event handlers bound to the original element are not copied to the clone. The optional `withDataAndEvents` parameter allows us to change this behavior, and to instead make copies of all of the event handlers as well, bound to the new copy of the element.

So you keep adding `click` event handlers to the `.clone` element. Depending on your actual case, just don't bind the event handler again:

```
var add = function(element) {
  var cloned = element.clone(true);
  $('.container').append(cloned);
}

$('.container .copy').click(function(){ 
    add($(this).closest('tr'));
});
```

*(I used `$(this).closest('tr')` to get the parent row. Obviously you have to adjust it to your needs.)*

**Update:**

Or don't pass `true`:

```
var add = function(element) {
    var cloned = element.clone();
    $('.container').append(cloned);
    $('.copy', cloned).click(function(){ add(cloned); });
}
```

Comment: i think this should be 'live' and not 'click' since the cloned object is new to the dom?

Comment: also, i want to comment that i wanted to put the 'copy' inside the add object so i don't have to worry about binding 'clicks' outside..this is a little bit of abstraction for the caller of my 'add' function, so they don't have to 'bind' the 'copy' click everytime.

Comment: @john: You clone the element, so all event handlers are cloned too. You could use `live` but then don't pass `true` to `clone`.

Comment: i've tried removing the 'true' value, and it doesn't still work. the copy click does nothing now.

Comment: is there any alternatives you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

`new` is JS keyword. Change it to something else and it should work.

( Your code does not have call of add() except of from itself. So it is not clear how code gets there initially. And recursive declaration of functions as in your code is a path to programmers hell )